# MCMC Metropolis Hastings for German Tank Puzzle

Tags: python, statistics, matplotlib, scipy, markov-chain

I have implemented the following MCMC algorithm for the german tank puzzle 
[found here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem)

I just want to make sure everything is legit and that I am not getting the right answer by chance.

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np
import math
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.stats import uniform

# Tank serial numbers collected in the field
data = np.array([10,20,50])


posterior = []
theta_current = 10  
num_samples = 10000
for i in range(num_samples):
    theta_proposal = uniform(max(data), 10000).rvs()

    likelihood_current = uniform(0, theta_current).pdf(data).prod()
    likelihood_proposal = uniform(0, theta_proposal).pdf(data).prod()

    p_accept = likelihood_proposal/likelihood_current

    accept = np.random.rand() < p_accept
    if accept:
                # Update position
        theta_current = theta_proposal
    posterior.append(theta_current)


#BURN IN
posterior = posterior[5000:]
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# define window size, output and axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[8,6])

# create histogram within output
N, bins, patches = ax.hist(posterior, bins=50, color="#777777") 
for bin_size, bin, patch in zip(N, bins, patches):
     if bin_size == 40:
         patch.set_facecolor("<some color like #FF000>")

plt.show()
```

Comment: It's a strange request to ask us to verify _"that I am not getting the right answer by chance"_... If you have tested the code, why do you suppose you might be getting the correct answer by chance, as opposed to by correct calculations? Please clarify what you mean.